# Undefined reference when using singleton class

Tags: c++

I have following test application for singleton class :

```
class my_singleton {
   private :
      my_singleton();
   public :
      static my_singleton& getinstance() {
         static my_singleton instance;
         return instance;
      }
    void demo() {
       std::cout << "demo !!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   my_singleton::getinstance().demo();
}
```

When i compile the same i get :

undefined reference to `my_singleton::my_singleton()'

Comment: Did you forget to define the default constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your constructor. Currently it is declared private, but not defined. Since your constructor is trivial, the best thing you can do is

```
   private :
      my_singleton() = default;
```

On a side note, you probably also want to `delete` copy constructor.

Comment: is default allowed in c++ ? is this with new std ?

Comment: @Dexter, it's from c++11, which I assume by `default` in 2016 (pun intended)